# Find Xpath hidden element in Quora page with Selenium - Python

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, selenium, xpath

I'm looking for take hidden question in this Quora webpage:
https://www.quora.com/topic/Python-programming-language-1/all_questions

I try to use this `Xpath:`

```
$x('//div[contains(@class, "pagedlist_item pagedlist_hidden")]')
```

and  works in firefox.
I want to use this in order to scroll down the webpage and stop the scroll when there is no more hidden elements in the page.

So i put in While loop in Selenium:

```
    posts_hidden = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name("pagedlist_item pagedlist_hidden"

    while len(posts_hidden)>0:

        self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

        if self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class,"pager_next")]').is_displayed():
            try:
                wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "pager_next")))
            except TimeoutException:
                self.driver.refresh()

        posts_hidden = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name("pagedlist_item pagedlist_hidden")
```

I use wait.until for stop the scrolldown when "`loading cycle`" of the page is on.

Someone can told me how to find the hidden post? or suggest bettern solution for ending the `scrolldown` of the page?

Comment: How about doing something like `posts_hidden.send_keys(Keys.END)`? It will scroll to the bottom of the page. Your loading will initiate and will not continue scrolling.

Comment: but how I can find post hidden?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _hidden post/question_?

Comment: I you see the html code of the page there are some Tags related to loaded questions thread for example: <div style="" class="pagedlist_item" tabindex="-1" id="ld_lshcdg_271"></div>. And there are loaded hidden question, that i can't view in the page but are loaded in html: <div style="display: none;" class="pagedlist_item pagedlist_hidden" tabindex="-1" id="ld_imdapn_1560"></div> - I need to take this field with xpath in Selenium

Comment: You can use this `hiddenAnswers = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("pagedlist_hidden")`.

Comment: Ok i try but if i print len(hiddenAnswers) return me 0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93151/discussion-between-jason-estibeiro-and-redvelvet).

Comment: By default, Selenium will not interact with hidden elements on the page. It's intended to simulate a user experience. You need to find what you need to click, etc. in the UI that will make that element visible and then code those steps.